# apt update error in kali linux NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6

Tags: linux, kali-linux

i'm trying to update my kali linux as usual but i got this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgNS2.png)

Pls help

Comment: As well as the duplicates, also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421821/invalid-signature-for-kali-linux-repositories-the-following-signatures-were-i